# Trying to select all the records from table B that have the same name as most recently added record from table A

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php and MySQL.  I have two tables.  I want to select all the records from table `PARTS` that have the same prod_name as the most recently added record in the table `PRODUCTS`.

Table `PRODUCTS`:

- id (auto increment)
- prod_name

Table `PARTS`:

- prod_name
- part_name
- part_cost

Will this work or should I use some sort of join?

```
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE prod_name = (SELECT prod_name FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: what happened when you executed the query?

Comment: I think what you have, with the nested select, is a good solution.

Comment: Why are you using prod_name instead of product_id in your parts table??

Comment: the prod_id is auto assigned when the part gets entered in the db.  the prod name won't change so it seemed like a decent solution.

Comment: If you're not going to use the ID, then why have it at all? Everyone else is able to use autoincrement IDs as foreign keys in their other tables, BTW. It's easy to do. MySQL returns the ID of the last autoincrement generated after an INSERT query... `mysql_insert_id()` in PHP... so that you can use it when inserting subsequent related rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work.  You can always execute the query in the phpmyadmin or MySql Query Browser to test it.

It may be better to return the inserted id, and select using that id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  parts.*
FROM
  parts
INNER JOIN
  products
ON
  products.prod_name = parts.prod_name
WHERE
  products.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM products)
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work - but if products has an auto increment id, why are you using the prod_name as the foreign key in the PARTS table?

Such a design buys you extra work if the user ever wants to change the prod_name (you then have to go through and change the prod_name on all the PARTS, unless you don't mind them losing their connection).

Plus it is not space efficient (unless prod_name is always very short).

Comment: prod name is always short and will never change.